# CodeIgniter session_destroy() logout back

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, redirect, destroy

How can I disable back when the user has pressed the logout button? This is my code

```
function logout(){
        session_start();
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        redirect(base_url(),'refresh');
    }
```

But everytime I click back, it gives me a "Confirm form resubmission" page and then when I reload it, the page before the logout function will be displayed

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't a silly mistake: If that form is for login, it's natural that re-submitting it will log you back in.

Comment: could you please add your view here .. You can simply `unset userdata ` in codeigniter. like `$this->session->unset_userdata($your_array);`

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following to the controllers I do not want people to access without being logged in:

Right after the class Name extends CI_Controller {

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    if ( ! $this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $allowed = array(
             // All allowed function names for not logged in users ( i keep it empty usually)
        );
        if ( ! in_array($this->router->fetch_method(), $allowed))
        {
            redirect(site_url('login/index'));
        }
    }
}
```

So basically what this does is before any function is accessed in the controller it will do a check if the user is logged in and if he/she isn't he/she will be redirected to the login page. (The userdata 'logged_in' part is what i set as userdata after person has logged in).

Answer (score 0):

Redirect already uses base_url() so you would make it like

```
redirect('yourdefaultcontroller', 'refresh');
```

and check session library, it makes your life easier

> https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this to prevent caching of the previous page:

```
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified:'.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').'GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: why ?? Any suggestion @santosh ??

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller**

> **`__construct` method add these**

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    ob_start(); # add this
    $this->load->library('Session'); # add this
}
```

**And In your method**

```
function logout(){
    $this->load->driver('cache'); # add
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); # Change
    $this->cache->clean();  # add
    redirect('home'); # Your default controller name 
    ob_clean(); # add
}
```

> **In `redirect` you have to set your default controller name.**

[Destroying a Session](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session%20class#destroying-a-session)